# React docs Keeping Components Pure Example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, jsx

I was going through the React Beta Docs https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure and came across this example in which they show what an impure component can be.

[image: Impure Component Example]

What I am not able to understand is that in line 5 we are incrementing the `guest` variable by 1, but why is it incrementing by 2 on every call to the `<Cup />` function as it it is getting rendered on the right?

Comment: This is written under _unintended consequences_ So I just wanted to point out that this is not the correct way to implement this use case. To your question: React 18 StrictMode mounts component twice to show developers if there is any unintended behaviors regarding component lifecycle. Therefore each `<Cup />` render increases guest twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the *Deep dive* lower on the page you linked to. When react is running in *Strict Mode*, each component is rendered twice when you are in development mode.

The relevant section:

> React offers a “Strict Mode” in which it calls each component’s function twice during development. By calling the component functions twice, Strict Mode helps find components that break these rules.
>
> Notice how the original example displayed “Guest #2”, “Guest #4”, and “Guest #6” instead of “Guest #1”, “Guest #2”, and “Guest #3”. The original function was impure, so calling it twice broke it. But the fixed pure version works even if the function is called twice every time. Pure functions only calculate, so calling them twice won’t change anything—just like calling double(2) twice doesn’t change what’s returned, and solving y = 2x twice doesn’t change what y is. Same inputs, same outputs. Always.

If you build the same code to production, you would instead see

```html
<h2>Tea cup for guest #1</h2>
<h2>Tea cup for guest #2</h2>
<h2>Tea cup for guest #3</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because with `<StrictMode>`, the component will render twice, So on each render the `guess` variable updates, So 2 * 4 will equal to 8.